# Pass Color to IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ivalueconverter

I am making a WPF application using the MVVM design pattern.  Part of the app is a signal strength bar.  We created it with just a rectangular user control and created a 4 column grid, so all we need to do is change either the background or foreground color of the control.

My idea on how to do this is a simply store Boolean values for each of the 4 sections and use a value converter.  However, there are 3 instances of this control, each with a different color.  How can I pass the needed color into the converter?  I know converters have a parameter argument, but I haven't been able to find any examples using it, so I'm not even sure if the parameter argument is what I'm looking for.

Comment: How is the converter used? I'm not understanding what you mean about changing the control background to change the bars. I wrote a five-segment signal strength control a couple weeks ago. Would it help if I just paste that in? You can trivially edit the template to change the segment count or whatever.

Comment: I suppose it could.  I figured the converter would just look at the boolean value for that section and change the background to either transparent or opaque.

Comment: I did it by writing a GreaterThan converter. The segments have a style trigger that sets the segment's fill to the "on" brush if the input value is greater than the segment's `Tag`.

Comment: Anyway, passing a brush to a converter's ConverterParameter is difficult. "White" wont' convert to `Brushes.White` because ConverterParameter is a string, so `BrushTypeConverter` isn't applied to the value the way it is if you're sticking "White" in a dependency property of type `Brush` in your XAML. Is that the problem you ran into? I've got a nifty workaround for passing typed values to converters. Actually it's not even a workaround.

Comment: I'm new to WPF (and MVVM), so not sure if this is just being nit-picky, but we were passing "alpha, red, green, blue" in during the initial setup and internal demo.  Now we're trying to fully implement it.  I'm not sure if using aRGB like that gets treated differently that just passing "white."  Otherwise yes, I think that is what I'm running into.

Comment: Do you mean `#800088ff` sort of colors? The brush converter converts strings in that format just as readily as named colors. Shouldn't be a problem at all. The only problem is getting the converter involved in the first place.

Comment: I do mean that sort of colors.  I assumed that it would use that just as readily, but like I said, I'm new, so wasn't certain.  I'll see if I can get your solution to work for me.  Thank you.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your question, but in this signal strength control, do you have four rectangles, one per grid column?  And if signal strength = 3, you want to have the first three rectangles green and the last one red?  Because you don't need a converter to do that.  Simple DataTriggers are all you need.

Comment: Yes, the signal strength is basically as you described it will.  It would seem that both you and Ed agree this solution is probably more complex than needed.  I'll look into the trigger option as well, but would that let me use different colors for each instance of the control?  There are three that are colored to correspond to different connections.

Comment: @eric If you need to specify differing colors for each, I'm gonna add my implementation to my answer. You'll have to alter the template a bit (remove the fifth segment, probably change segment height and width values to suit your taste) but that's little stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your case may not be best addressed by the method you've chosen (it makes it hard to parameterize the colors of the segments), but your specific question is a good one, so I'll answer it.

As you've found, it's tough to pass anything but a string to `ConverterParameter`. but you don't have to. If you derive a converter from `MarkupExtension`, you can assign named and typed properties when you use it, and also not have to create it as a resource (indeed, creating it as a resource would break the thing, since that would be a shared instance and the properties are initialized when it's created). Since the XAML parser knows the types of the properties declared on the class, it will apply the default `TypeConverter` for `Brush`, and you'll get the exact same behavior as if you were assigning `"PapayaWhip"` to `"Border.Background"` or anything else.

This works with any type, of course, not just `Brush`.

```
namespace HollowEarth.Converters
{
    public class BoolBrushConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        public Brush TrueBrush { get; set; }
        public Brush FalseBrush { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return System.Convert.ToBoolean(value) ? TrueBrush : FalseBrush;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<TextBox 
    xmlns:hec="clr-namespace:HollowEarth.Converters"
    Foreground="{Binding MyFlagProp, Converter={hec:BoolBrushConverter TrueBrush=YellowGreen, FalseBrush=DodgerBlue}}" 
    />
```

You could give `BoolBrushConverter` a constructor that takes parameters, too.

```
public BoolBrushConverter(Brush tb, Brush fb)
{
    TrueBrush = tb;
    FalseBrush = fb;
}
```

And in XAML...

```
<TextBox 
    xmlns:hec="clr-namespace:HollowEarth.Converters"
    Foreground="{Binding MyFlagProp, Converter={hec:BoolBrushConverter YellowGreen, DodgerBlue}}" 
    />
```

I don't think that's a good fit for this case. But sometimes the semantics are so clear, the property name is unnecessary. `{hec:GreaterThan 4.5}`, for example.

## UPDATE

Here's a complete implementation of a SignalBars control. This has five segments to your four, but you can easily remove one; that's only in the template, and the `Value` property is a `double` that could be subdivided any way you like (again, in the template).

SignalBars.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace HollowEarth
{
    public class SignalBars : ContentControl
    {
        static SignalBars()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SignalBars), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SignalBars)));
        }

        #region Value Property
        public double Value
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(SignalBars),
                new PropertyMetadata(0d));
        #endregion Value Property

        #region InactiveBarFillBrush Property
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("White")]
        public Brush InactiveBarFillBrush
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(InactiveBarFillBrushProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InactiveBarFillBrushProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InactiveBarFillBrushProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InactiveBarFillBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(SignalBars),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.White));
        #endregion InactiveBarFillBrush Property
    }

    public class ComparisonConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public virtual object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Length != 2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Exactly two values are expected");
            }

            var d1 = GetDoubleValue(values[0]);
            var d2 = GetDoubleValue(values[1]);

            return Compare(d1, d2);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Overload in subclasses to create LesserThan, EqualTo, whatever.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a"></param>
        /// <param name="b"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected virtual bool Compare(double a, double b)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected static double GetDoubleValue(Object o)
        {
            if (o == null || o == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    return System.Convert.ToDouble(o);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

    public class GreaterThan : ComparisonConverter
    {
        protected override bool Compare(double a, double b)
        {
            return a > b;
        }
    }
}
```

Themes\Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >

    <Style 
        xmlns:he="clr-namespace:HollowEarth"
        TargetType="{x:Type he:SignalBars}" 
        >
        <!-- Foreground is the bar borders and the fill for "active" bars -->
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="InactiveBarFillBrush" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="4" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding InactiveBarFillBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,1,0" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{he:GreaterThan}">
                                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                <Binding 
                                                    Path="Value" 
                                                    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" 
                                                    />
                                                <Binding 
                                                    Path="Tag" 
                                                    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" 
                                                    />
                                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <ContentControl
                        ContentTemplate="{Binding ContentTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <StackPanel 
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            UseLayoutRounding="True"
                            >
                            <!-- Set Tags to the minimum threshold value for turning the segment "on" -->
                            <!-- Remove one of these to make it four segments. To make them all equal height, remove Height here
                            and set a fixed height in the Rectangle Style above. -->
                            <Rectangle Height="4" Tag="0" />
                            <Rectangle Height="6" Tag="2" />
                            <Rectangle Height="8" Tag="4" />
                            <Rectangle Height="10" Tag="6" />
                            <Rectangle Height="12" Tag="8" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ContentControl>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Example XAML:

```
<StackPanel 
    xmlns:he="clr-namespace:HollowEarth"
    Orientation="Vertical"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    >
    <Slider 
        Minimum="0" 
        Maximum="10" 
        x:Name="SignalSlider" 
        Width="200" 
        SmallChange="1" 
        LargeChange="4" 
        TickFrequency="1" 
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" 
        />
    <he:SignalBars 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Value="{Binding Value, ElementName=SignalSlider}" 
        InactiveBarFillBrush="White" 
        Foreground="DarkRed"
        />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I will investigate your code and see how/if I can adapt it to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you may need a `ColorToBrushConverter`, but not a BooleanToColor.

I would simply create different styles with triggers for each bar, like

```
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOffline}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Salmon" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPrinting}" Value="True">
                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Honeydew" />-->
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```